# Передача данных между формой ввода и скриптом js

Tags: json, html, ajax, form

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, как можно передать переменные из формы ввода:

```
<form>
    <label for="A">Откуда </label><input id="A" name="A" value="" type="text"><br>
    <label for="B">Куда</label><input id="B" name="B" value="" type="text"><br>
    <input value="Send" type="submit">
</form>
```

в js скрипт (yandex map), расположенный в другом файле.

Насколько я понимаю, из доступных способов:
Url, cockie, Json, Ajax.

Что посоветуете использовать?
По json  и ajax  не нашел, как использовать для передачи между двумя js  файлами.
Заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать обычный javascript.
В скрипте yandex map, скорее всего, есть функция, которая принимает значения из формы. Представим, что это функция *FromTo(A,B)*. Так как это js скрипт, то можно вызвать эту функцию нажатием кнопки Send.

При нажатии браузер пошлёт значения формы в функцию `FromTo()`.

```
<form onsubmit="FromTo(A.value, B.value)">
    <label for="A">Откуда </label><input name="A"><br>
    <label for="B">Куда</label><input name="B"><br>
    <input value="Send" type="submit">
</form>
```

P.S. Должен быть подключен скрипт yandex map.